# Как убрать прямоугольник при смене рабочего стола?

Tags: linux, gnome

Когда переключаю рабочие пространства в Gnome 41.5 с помощью ctrl+alt появляется маленький прямоугольник где указанно на какое окно я переключился,как его убрать а то он сильно раздражает ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

в 42.0 её уменьшили. Этот индикатор можно убрать написав своё расширение, но проще написать свою тему, которая выставит css этого элемента в полную прозрачность.

Классы можно посмотреть в /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic.css

```
/* Workspace Switcher */
.workspace-switcher {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  spacing: 12px;
  padding: 12px 18px; }

.ws-switcher-indicator {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 0.1816666667em;
  margin: 0.9083333333em;
```